# Toggling a div with JQuery and having link text switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code where you click on a link and jQuery opens a div. In its normal state the link says "Watch Video", I'd like to have it work so that when the div becomes visible the link text changes to "Close video". Clicking on the close video link closes the div.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/XsvG9/

Here's the actual code:

JS

```
$("span.trigger a").click(function() {
    the_id = $(this).attr('id');

$("#toggle_container-"+the_id).slideToggle(500, function() {
    $("span.trigger a"+the_id).text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close video' : 'Watch video');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<p class="data">Posted Feb 20 | <a href="/supersecret/jsmith/post/399/">0 comments</a> |<span id="votes_count399" class="votes_count"> 0 </span>

<span id="vote_buttons399" class="vote_buttons">faves<a id="399" title="Favorite This" class="vote_up" href="javascript:;">#</a></span> | <span class="trigger"><a id="399" href="javascript:;">Watch video</a></span>
</p>

<div class="hide" id="toggle_container-399" style="display: none;">
    <iframe width="555" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/z1c1OIMbmb0"/></div>
</div>
```

I have it working where the div toggles open, but the link does not switch text. I've been staring at this too long, so I would appreciate it if a fresh pair of eyes could help find the error in my ways.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your anchors have same id `399` which is what is creating the main problem.

Instead of `.text()` method, use `.html()` to change the text as well.

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XsvG9/3/) removes all the problem and works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly how I want it to. I had a feeling it was something simple I was overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know is that you cannot use duplicate IDs. You have 2 anchors with the same ID - this is invalid and will only cause problems with multiple movies on the same page. If you store the ID in a data attribute, you can reuse it to select the correct movie element to show. You should also give your anchors classes so you can control the different functions (favourite, toggle etc)

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-movie-id="399" class="watch">Watch video</a>
```

js:

```
$("span.trigger a.watch").click(function() {
    the_id = $(this).attr('data-movie-id');
    anchor = $(this);

    $("#toggle_container-" + the_id).slideToggle(500, function() {
        anchor.text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close video' : 'Watch video');

    });
});
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XsvG9/7/

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try as well as it seems to clean things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the extra span around the link, add the toggle div's id to the href of the link, then add a span around the text for the link:

```
$(".trigger").click( function(){
var lnk = $(this).attr("href");
$(lnk).slideToggle(300, "easeInOutSine");
}).toggle(
  function(){
       $(this).children('span').html('Close ');},
   function(){
        $(this).children('span').html('Watch ');
  })
```

[**Working Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/XsvG9/8/)

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the id from link you clicked, then using that id to create a selector later on just to reference back to "this"

```
$("span.trigger a").click(function() {
      the_id = $(this).attr('id');  

    $(this).text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close video' : 'Watch video');

    $("#toggle_container-"+the_id).slideToggle(500);

    return false;
});
```

Updated example  http://jsfiddle.net/XsvG9/2/

Within the click handler "this" refers to the element in your selector that you actually clicked on

Comment: The link will always be visible, the :visible check needs to be performed on the toggle_container, not the link.